# Maven - maven-plugin-api, maven-project and other jars in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, maven, war

I have a maven build that is copying a bunch of jars that it should not be into WEB-INF/lib for my war project.

The jars do not show up in the output of `mvn dependency:tree` but `mvn package` puts these (among other) jars into the WEB-INF/lib directory of the generated war file:

maven-artifact, maven-artifcat-manager, maven-profile, maven-project, maven-settings...

Where are these coming from?  What (other than dependency:tree) might show me what is causing these jars to be included?  I have done a `mvn clean` and rebuild and same thing.

It seems that when I add this plugin I get the extra jars added:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>xmlbeans-generate-compile</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
          <goal>xmlbeans-test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
      <sourceGenerationDirectory>src/xmlbean/java</sourceGenerationDirectory>
      <classGenerationDirectory>target/xmlbean/build</classGenerationDirectory>
      <schemaDirectory>src/main/components</schemaDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The rest of the POM is just dependency stuff and this:

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
          <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/tests</additionalClasspathElement>
          </additionalClasspathElements>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Could you post your POM (or a simplified version of it)?

Comment: I'd rather not, any particular sections you think might be the culprit?

Comment: Well, since this isn't supposed to happen, it's hard to identify it... Are you triple extra sure that it doesn't appear in `mvn dependency:tree`? How is your WAR built? Does the project have `war` packaging? Is there someone adding things manually to `WEB-INF/lib` with the `maven-dependency:plugin` for example? This is very unusual. I would try to cut down your POM piece by piece, until you have something truly minimal that reproduces the problem. Start by removing dependencies, all of your Java sources, all other modules, etc... Hard to debug without seeing the project.

Comment: @Tunaki is correct - we cannot help you unless you help us to help you. These jars are not coming from nowhere; some dep' brings them. put the pom.xml (or the main parts of it) so we can try to help

Comment: OK, so I'll remove all the java sources and see if that does it.  If not, I'll remove all the dependencies and see which one triggers it.  I can't really post it due to NDA reasons and all that

Comment: Check out the update.  I had a bunch of dependencies to work out, and when I added the xmlbeans plugin the funky jars started showing up

Comment: Hrm, is your NDA so restrictive you can't post an xml file with any identifying information removed? That's pretty unfortunate